# Deduct 10% from recordset number

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

Is it possible to run a calculation when presenting a number from a recordset to a webpage

I want to deduct 10% off the number in the database.

I've tried the below:

```
 <%=((Recordset1.Fields.Item("FullCover").Value)*90/100)%>
```

But it just returns

```
-1.#IND
```

Comment: This isn't javascript. You're running ASP.net code within a HTML-page. Please tag appropriately.

Comment: I'm running ASP Javascript

Comment: The confusion comes from Classic ASP accepting the `@LANGUAGE` directive of `JavaScript` which is just an alias for `JScript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is effectively returning `Not a Number` or (`NaN`).

Answer will be :

```
<%=((parseInt(Recordset1.Fields.Item("FullCover").Value, 10))*90/100)%>
```

It will parse the item out of the recordset into an integer and then performs the calculations.

Also a simple `* 0.90` would do the trick. Saves one calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using ASP Classic Javascript so that won't work.

Comment: That's returning the following error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a138f'

Object expected

Comment: Then try using `parseInt()` instead of `CInt`.

Comment: Returning the following:

1.#QNAN

Comment: What value is `Recordset1.Fields.Item("FullCover").Value` returning?

Comment: Working now, you triggered something. The field in the database was "10" however the field was set as a text field. I've changed it to a number field and it now works. I've using parse(Int). Thanks for your help

Comment: I can't add a score due to rep being under 15

Comment: @Lankymart OP wasn't really providing the correct info on what kind of language he was using, or what value returned. The basic of the answer stands however.

Comment: Actually the OP tagged the question correctly you misinterpreted the technologies being used and edited the tags incorrectly. That being said the *final* answer is accurate.

Comment: @Lankymart, yeah not quite. It's actually jScript running in an ASP environment. Which is of course basically the same as JavaScript.

Comment: The fact [tag:asp-classic] was included should be enough to make the jump from [tag:javascript] to [tag:jscript]. Either way its not [tag:jscript.net] *(is there such a thing?)* or [tag:c#] for that matter. **Edit:** Well after checking the about page I guess there is either way it's not what is being used here.